# Javascript create an image and make it move

Tags: javascript, html, animation, move

I'm trying to make a little browser game where you can shoot bullets.
Right now I am able to make a bullet, but I don't know how to get in moving.

I have done this:

```
var bullet_id = 1;

                var timer_id; // reference of the timer, needed to stop it
                var speed = 350; // pixels/second
                var period = 10; // milliseconds
                var sprite; // the element that will move
                var sprite_speed = 0; // move per period
                var sprite_position = 315; // pixels

                function createbullet() {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = "images/bullet.png";
                    img.id = "bullet";
                    img.name = "bullet";
                    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
                    foo.appendChild(img);
                    move(1);
                    bullet_id++;
                }

                function animate ()
                {
                    document.getElementById("bullet").style.left=340 + "px";
                    sprite_position += sprite_speed;
                    sprite.style.left = sprite_position+'px';
                }

                function move(direction)
                {
                    if (timer_id) stop();
                    sprite_speed = speed * period/1000 * direction;
                    timer_id = setInterval (animate, period);
                }

                function stop()
                {
                    clearInterval (timer_id);
                    timer_id = null;
                }

                function init()
                {
                   sprite = document.getElementById ("bullet"); // the HTML element we will move
                   animate(); // just to initialize sprite position
                }

                window.onload = init; // start doing things once the page has loaded    */
```

I tried to add a bullet_id system but I couldn't get it working really.

Here is my html

```
<a onmousedown="document.jack.src=image2.src;" onmouseup="document.jack.src=image1.src;" onclick="createbullet()"><img id="jack" name="jack" src="/images/jack1.png" /></a>

            <div id="fooBar"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: u want to move it onclick or just follow the mouse position

Comment: I want to make the created "bullet" object move to the left, when `<a onmousedown="document.jack.src=image2.src;" onmouseup="document.jack.src=image1.src;" onclick="createbullet()"><img id="jack" name="jack" src="/images/jack1.png" /></a>` is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('jack').addEventListener('click',function(){...})
```

Ok so maybe I didn't think that one through, have just designed one to see if I could and it works, hope it helps:

```
/********************************************************/
stg=0
bgx=0
spd=70
buls=0
act=false
/********************************************************/
function ani(){
    var int
    act=true
    bgx-=52
    stg++
    $('#jack').css('background-position','-52px 0px')
    int=setInterval(function(){
        if(stg<4){bgx-=52;  stg++}
            else{   bgx=0;      stg=0 }
        $('#jack').css('background-position',bgx+'px 0px')
        if(stg==4)  new Bullet();
        if(!stg){
            act=false
            clearInterval(int)
        }
    },spd)
}
/********************************************************/
function Bullet(){
    var x,img,int
    x=52
    img=document.createElement('img')
        img.src='bullet.png'
        img.setAttribute('class','mh posAbs')
        img.setAttribute('style','top:0px;left:'+x+'px')
        img.setAttribute('id','bul'+buls)
    scre.appendChild(img)
    img=document.getElementById('bul'+buls)
    buls++
    int=setInterval(function(){
        if(x<300){
            x+=13
            img.setAttribute('style','top:0px;left:'+x+'px')
        }
            else{
                img.src='exp.png'
                clearInterval(int)
                setTimeout(function(){ scre.removeChild(img) },100)
            }
    },spd)
}
/********************************************************/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').keydown(function(){
        if(!act){
            if(event.keyCode==13)   ani();
        }
    })
    $('html').click(function(){
        if(!act)    ani();
    })
})
/********************************************************/
```

---

```
<div id="scre" class="posRel">
    <div id="jack"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
<style>
    #jack{
        width:52px;
        height:37px;
        background:url('02.png') no-repeat;
        background-position:0px 0px;
        background-size:auto 100%
    }
</style>
```

---

Ok so what's happening above is every time you click or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the firing animation is called, which is animated in stages and when it gets to a certain stage it calls upon the `Bullet()` constructor to create a new `Object` or bullet.

While creating the **bullet**, the constructor generates an `<img>` and gives it a unique id based upon the `buls` variable, which is then incremented to keep the id's unique.

**This** is the most important part:

```
img=document.getElementById('bul'+buls)
```

It will **NOT** work without it as any references to `img` in the code after it will refer to the last `img` created and not say:- 'bullet 5 of 10 that are on screen'.

Once created the `Bullet` object handles the movement of the image it is referenced to, removing the need to move it with any other code...

---

**P.S.** The `$('html').keydown(...)` acts as an auto-fire!

---

Comment: I have gotten that done (not the same way, but working). The problem is how do I get 1 bullet moving, when I click on 'jack'. And how do I name them uniqually and then call that specific bullet that was created.